# Matlab: index array by Hamming Weights

Tags: matlab, hammingweight

`a` contains indices and their occurrences. Now the indexing needs to be changed with Hamming weight so that indices with equal hamming weight will be summed up. How to do the Hamming weight indexing? Any ready command for this in Matlab?

```
>> a=[1,2;2,3;5,2;10,1;12,2]

     1     2
     2     3
     5     2
    10     1
    12     2
    13     8


>> dec2bin(a(:,1))

ans =

0001
0010
0101
1010
1100
1101
```

**Goal:** index things by Hamming weight

```
HW    Count
1     5 (=2+3)
2     5 (=2+1+2)
3     8 (=8)
```

Comment: ERR...I realised an easier solution to original prob, just use HW over the whole initial vector like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9397290/164148 and then just `hist(HW)`. Thank you for your input anyway, the simplest solution rocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
a = [1,2;2,3;5,2;10,1;12,2;13,8]
```

the following line needs to be added, to consider also a hammingweight of zero:

```
if nnz(a(:,1)) == numel(a(:,1)); a = [0,0;a]; end
% or just
a = [0,0;a];   %// wouldn't change the result
```

to get the indices

```
rowidx = sum( de2bi(a(:,1)), 2 )
```

to get the sums

```
sums = accumarray( rowidx+1, a(:,2) ) %// +1 to consider Hammingweight of zero
```

to get the Hammingweight vector

```
HW = unique(rowidx)
```

returns:

```
rowidx =

     1
     1
     2
     2
     2
     3


sums =

     5
     5
     8
```

and all together:

```
result = [HW, sums]
%or
result = [unique(rowidx), accumarray(rowidx+1,a(:,2))]

result =

     0     0
     1     5
     2     5
     3     8
```

If you are bothered by the `0  0` line, filter it out

```
result(sum(result,2)>0,:)
```

The result for `a = [0,2;2,3;5,2;10,1;12,2;13,8]` would be:

```
result =

     0     2
     1     3
     2     5
     3     8
```

Comment: ...missing the HW column.

Comment: Why is this failing with `a = [0,2;2,3;5,2;10,1;12,2;13,8]; rowidx = sum( de2bi(a(:,1)), 2 ); sums = accumarray( rowidx, a(:,2) )`?

Comment: @hhh: "Why" is obvious, because the hammingweight is used as index, which is invalid for zero. Fixed, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
a = [1     2
     2     3
     5     2
    10     1
    12     2
    13     8]

HW = dec2bin(a(:,1)) - '0'; 

out = accumarray(sum(HW,2), a(:,2), [], @sum);%%// You don't need that "sum" option it seems, as that's the default operation with accumarray

final_out = [unique(sum(HW,2)) out]
```

Output -

```
a =

     1     2
     2     3
     5     2
    10     1
    12     2
    13     8


final_out =

     1     5
     2     5
     3     8
```